# Setting the `type` of @Input at runtime : Angular & typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generics

I have a component which displays data and also `emit` event on a click (after doing some calculation on it)

So **display.component**

```
type ClickEvent = {
  data: any, //<-- it should be same as @input data
  something: number;
}
export class DisplayComponent{

 @Input() data: any;

 @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<ClickEvent>() 

 buttonClicked(){
    this.clicked.emit({data: this.data , something: 2})
  }

}
```

I want to make sure that the `@Output` and `@Input` are of same type. So the the user can use intellisense to access the `$event` which is being sent as `this.clicked.emit(this.data)`

Comment: If your type is predicted, then you can use interface and adds interface as type to both input and output. That's more easy for you to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Generics to the rescue

```js
type ClickEvent<TEventData> = {
  data: TEventData, 
  something: number;
}
export class DisplayComponent<TComponentData>{

 @Input() data: TComponentData;

 @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<ClickEvent<TComponentData>>();

 buttonClicked(){
    this.clicked.emit({data: this.data , something: 2})
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have made an update in the question. Sincere apologies for changing the question little bit

Comment: When I try to assign a value like `@Input() data: TComponentData = { p1: 'Val1' }` , it doesn't accept it. Says `is not assignable to type 'TComponentData'.`

Comment: that is not that easy to address. Here is the possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52477831/390161