# TypeScript: Generic Type based on optional constructor parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I type the function getFormattedOrOriginal correctly, so it automatically returns type B if formatter was not set in constructor?

```js
class Test<A, B = A> {
  constructor(private value: A, private formatter?: (x: A) => B) {}

  getFormattedOrOriginal(): B {
    return this.formatter ? this.formatter(this.value) : this.value;
  }
}

// Expected:
new Test(3).getFormattedOrOriginal() === 3
new Test(3, x => x.toString()).getFormattedOrOriginal() === "3"
```

Only solution I found was to use `this.value as unknown as B`, which is definitly bad.

Comment: You indicted a wider type as a return value so `value` which is always has the A type cannot be returned. Either change the return type to A or to A | B

Comment: Your question looks like the one I asked a few years ago. Maybe the answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476818/default-value-and-generics-in-typescript

Comment: @Anatoly There was a typo, formatter is optional.
What exactly do you mean?
- If formatter is set, it is called and returns B
- If formatter is not set, this.value of type A is returned, and as B = A, it also returns B.

Comment: B = A only by default and that means you can pass something wider

Comment: Then you can indicate `private value: B`

Comment: I have added an usage example to clarify what is the expected output. It is my intention to be able to pass something wider, and I expect that either A or B is returned, depending on whether formatter is specified.

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret I do not see how this solves the problem?

Comment: Nothing stops callers from specifying `B` manually while also not passing in a `formatter`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mM8QdN) so there really is no guarantee that your function can return a `B`.  All the workarounds I can think of are beyond the ability of the compiler to verify, so you will have to do something equivalent to a type assertion, which you are saying is "definitely bad".  So I'm not sure how to proceed.